# How to multiply to columns in different table and get another column as output in django orm

Tags: django, django-models, orm, django-orm

I have three tables :

- First one is product table consist of product details and price
- Second one is customer table with customer details
- And a cart table with customer_id and product _id as foreign key and qty field for quantity of product

I want join cart table and product table and get an additional column called total price that is the result of price in product *qty in cart

How to do this in django orm

I tried f function but it didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this.

```
Cart.objects.annotate(total_price=F('product__price')*F('qty'))
```